# Select column from one table order by column from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

**Customer_Master**:

```
 CUSTOMER_ID    CUSTOMER_NAME 
 ----------------------------
   1             Test1
   2             Test2
```

**Ticket_Master**:

```
 TICKETID   CUSTOMER_ID     UPDATEDATE
 --------------------------------------------------
    1           1           2017-03-03 00:00:00.000
    2           1           2017-03-20 20:09:31.000
    3           2           2017-03-20 20:11:00.000
    4           2           2017-03-20 20:15:29.000
```

I need results with all elements from Table 1 order by updatetime of Ticket_Mater. Join results in Duplicate rows whereas I need distinct rows from Customer_Master.

```
SELECT 
    a.CUSTOMER_ID, MAX(b.UPDATEDATE)
FROM 
    customer_master AS a 
INNER JOIN
    Ticket_master AS b ON a.CUSTOMER_ID = b.CUSTOMERID 
GROUP BY 
    a.CUSTOMER_ID 
ORDER BY 
    MAX(b.UPDATEDATE) DESC
```

Above query returns order by update but not all elements of customer_master.

```
SELECT  
    a.*, b.UPDATEDATE
FROM 
    customer_master AS a
INNER  JOIN 
    Ticket_master AS b ON a.customer_id = b.customerid
ORDER BY 
    b.UPDATEDATE desc
```

This Query Return Duplicate rows from Ticket_master.

Please help. Every Help will be highly Appreciated.

Comment: Is there any expected result?

Comment: Thanks @Mitch for formatting my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there can be several entries in `Ticket_Master` for a `CUSTOMER_ID` you must decide by which of the possible dates to sort. This would usually be the first or the latest date per `CUSTOMER_ID`.

You can do this with a subquery:

```
select *
from customer_master cm
order by
(
  select max(tm.updatedate)
  from ticket_master tm
  where tm.customer_id = cm.customer_id
) desc;
```

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten Kettner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT distinct(a.*)
FROM customer_master AS a inner join
                      Ticket_master AS b ON a.CUSTOMER_ID = b.CUSTOMERID 
order by b.UPDATEDATE desc
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, so the parentheses are superfluous. Moreover this is not valid SQL as `b.UPDATEDATE` is not available in the result rows (`distinct a.*`), so you cannot order by it.